# Looking for controls on parent page from DevExpress ASPXPopUpControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

good sirs!

I've been messing around with the next scenario:

First, I have a webform structured as a WebForm containing a DevExpress ASPXPopUpControl and some other controls. Inside the PopUpControl there is a UserControl (lets call it ucA) containing some other controls and a UserControl (called ucB) that contains a cursed ASPxHtmlEditor (added because it's a new requirement).

When the user hits a button on main webform I show the PopUp (originally was a jQuery dialog but since HTMLEditor messes up with jQuery I've been forced to break the standard and use the popup) which contains the ucA. The user fills some fields in ucA and hit the save button. After user hits, I save some dataz and at this point I need to recover a textbox value placed in the webform.

I'm using Parent.FindControl["myTextBox"] but it considers the popupcontrol as parent. When I was using jQuery (before implementing the editor) it worked like a charm.

I feel it's something trivial but thrust me when I say that this stole many hours of research.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** I forgot to mention that I want to look for another UserControl at main webform. This uc its used to display core messages to the user so when he hits the save button, save happens, popup is closed and i look (Parent.FindControl("myUCMessageBoard")) from the ucA for the usercontrol to display a "Transaction complete" message.

Comment: Where are you calling Parent.FindControl()?  From ucA or from ucB?

Comment: From ucA since there's where the save process is being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking you're going to have to do something a little hacky, by using `ViewState`.  If I understand correctly, you are trying to get access to a `TextBox`'s `Text` on the Web Form, from a UserControl nested within a PopupControl (so you can't traverse all the way up to Web Form Level).

So, what I'd do at some point in the process is store the text in a ViewState variable that you can access from the User Control.  It's not optimal, but since you're already hacking to get it to work, what's a little more hacking?

Comment: Well, didnt thought about that to be honest. For the Textbox case should be enough, thanks! I made a little update to the question, i missed the mention somegthing.

Comment: What you may want to do is expose ucA's Save method as `public`, then you can FindControl from the main Web Form, call Save, and if successful, display the success message.

Answer (score 0):

You should expose all controls from ucA as properties, then look for the control inside the DevxPopup the same way you doing. Given that all the controls that you need at the ucA has properties to access them, you could do all the logic you need!

Example:

```
public ucA : UserControl
{
    public string myTextBoxText 
    { 
        get 
        {
            return ((TextBox)Controls.FindControl("myTextBox")).Text;
        }
    }
    /*And lot of controls*/
}
```

Then you looking for the popup at the Form

```
var ucA = (UcA)Form.Controls.FindControl("myPopup").Controls.FindControl("myucA");
ucA.myTextBoxText = /*Do stuff here with the text*/
```

Hopes this help you!

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I'll try to implement your answer altogether with Garrison's answer. Both approaches gave me a good idea.